# Select music before game start in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a scene which is all my music in this scene. I create a button for each music and I push the button and select my music. After that it will switch the game scene and game start with the music which I chose... in Unity C#. you do not have to tell me how the button create, I just need the codes...

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

you can create the MusicObject in that scene, choose the music with that button and use :

```
DontDestroyOnLoad (MusicObjbect.gameObject);
```

so i can still be present in the next scene as well.
hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create array of music, and it indexes.
After tap button, save index.
On load new scene, add to Audio source music with saved index